# MYSQL top of division between two queries

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two queries, first is to get top 10 sales by hour and another to get top visitors by hour

```
SELECT HOUR(fechaRegistreoDatetime) AS laHora, 
ROUND( IFNULL(SUM(tickets.precioTotal),0) , 2 ) AS CantidadVenta 
FROM tickets 
WHERE fechaRegistreoDatetime BETWEEN '2017-01-20 00:00:00' and '2017-01-30 23:59:59' 
group by HOUR(fechaRegistreoDatetime) 
ORDER BY CantidadVenta DESC LIMIT 10



SELECT HOUR(horaLocal) AS laHora, horaLocal, 
COUNT(*) AS Cantidad FROM poepleCounter  
where horaLocal BETWEEN '2017-01-20 00:00:00' and '2017-01-30 23:59:59' 
group by HOUR(horaLocal) 
ORDER BY Cantidad DESC LIMIT 10
```

I need to generate a new top 10 of the division between this two queries **(CantidadVenta / Cantidad)** , can someone help me ?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
select * from 
(
SELECT HOUR(fechaRegistreoDatetime) AS laHora, 
ROUND( IFNULL(SUM(tickets.precioTotal),0) , 2 ) AS CantidadVenta 
FROM tickets 
WHERE fechaRegistreoDatetime BETWEEN '2017-01-20 00:00:00' and '2017-01-30 23:59:59' 
group by HOUR(fechaRegistreoDatetime) 
) A
Join
(
SELECT HOUR(fechaRegistreoDatetime) AS laHora, 
ROUND( IFNULL(SUM(tickets.precioTotal),0) , 2 ) AS CantidadVenta 
FROM tickets 
WHERE fechaRegistreoDatetime BETWEEN '2017-01-20 00:00:00' and '2017-01-30 23:59:59' 
group by HOUR(fechaRegistreoDatetime) 
) B 
ON A.laHora = B.laHora
ORDER BY CantidadVenta / Cantidad DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thakks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

this was my final code, thanks to Prdp!

```
select *, (CantidadVenta / Cantidad) as Conversion from 
(
SELECT HOUR(fechaRegistreoDatetime) AS laHora, 
ROUND( IFNULL(SUM(tickets.precioTotal),0) , 2 ) AS CantidadVenta 
FROM tickets 
WHERE fechaRegistreoDatetime BETWEEN '2017-01-20 00:00:00' and '2017-01-30 23:59:59' 
group by HOUR(fechaRegistreoDatetime) 
) A
Join
(
SELECT HOUR(horaLocal) AS laHora, horaLocal, 
COUNT(*) AS Cantidad FROM poepleCounter  
where horaLocal BETWEEN '2017-01-20 00:00:00' and '2017-01-30 23:59:59' 
group by HOUR(horaLocal) 
) B 
ON A.laHora = B.laHora
ORDER BY (CantidadVenta / Cantidad) DESC LIMIT 10
```